# Grails formRemote multipart catch data onSucess

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, multipart

i´m just working on a foto-upload with Grails, when i use g:form
everything works fine, the file gets parsed, transformed and put into session in controller
and as response i render a template containing the foto and some hidden inputs because the next step is to crop the image and send back the new coordinates..

this is the "uploadForm" code :

```
<g:form name="uploadForm" onSuccess="sucess()" enctype="multipart/form-data" url="[controller:ProfileEditor, action:"preview${type.capitalize()}", params:[profilId:profilId]]" >
<input type="file" name="${type}" />
<input type="submit" value="<g:message code="button.${type}.upload" />">
</g:form>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function success() {
        $('#uploadPreview').html(data);
    alert("upload complete");   
}
</script>
```

i want the response to be inserted into

```
('#uploadPreview')
```

instead on clicking submit button, the browser navigates to the url as specified in url-attr containing the template with the image

the problem is that there is no data posted when i use g:formRemote, just like the enctype="multipart/form-data" is completly ignored, afaik it is a bit tricky to upload files via ajax, we already solved that with jquery form.js and it´s ajaxForm, it didn´t need a formRemote, and made it possible to upload the foto in the same page, but we can´t use it anymore it caused serious session-issues and script errors randomly in chrome /ium and opera
so i must find another way

this was the simple form.js way right where in the code above the sucessFunction is:

```
-       var options =  {
-           beforeSubmit : function() {
-               uploadPreview.empty();
                },  
-           complete : function(xhr) {
-               percent.empty();
-               uploadPreview.html(xhr.responseText);
-           }
-       };
-       $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

and i wonder if there ain´t a there a simple solution to use formRemote to post the file as formData and update the div, as an ajax-foto upload with cropping inside a wrapping form is a common thing  ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You said that you're using `g:formRemote`, but code have only standard `g:form`

Comment: indeed, i just updated the Question